# android -Edit Text background get red on TextInputLayout error

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

It's very strange problem, this is my code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_pass"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="37dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_https_grey600_18dp"
                    app:hintEnabled="false"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/password"
                        style="@style/edittexts"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_https_grey600_18dp"
                       android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_https_grey600_18dp"
                        android:hint="رمز عبور"
                        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:transformPivotX="10dp"
                        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I am using TextInputLayout for my login process, this is my java code :

pass_l.setErrorEnabled(true);
pass_l.setError(getString(R.string.wrong_pass));

When it show the error, the background of edit text gets red and it doesn't show the error below it , some thing like this :

[image]

how can I fix this problem? I don't want the edittext change the background color , just show the error below the editext as usual

Comment: what is inside your edittexts style ? can you share

Comment: @MishaAkopov , the style is for bordering the edittext , I removed it but it doesn't make any different

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your style="@style/edittexts".Please shhare source code of it.It must be set Red in this style.

Comment: the style is for bordering the edittext , I removed it but it doesn't make any different

Comment: Please check another answer as i have added.

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_pass"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="37dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                    android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_https_grey600_18dp"
                    app:hintEnabled="false"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/password"
                        style="@style/edittexts"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_https_grey600_18dp"
                       android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_https_grey600_18dp"
                        android:hint="رمز عبور"
                        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:transformPivotX="10dp"
                        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>



<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/Color Name</item> 
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/Color Name</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/Color Name</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/Color Name</item>
 </style>
```

You can try like this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in your textInputLayoutTag :

```
app:errorEnabled="true"
app:errorTextAppearance="@style/ErrorAppearance"
```

example :

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_pass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_https_grey600_18dp"
        app:hintEnabled="false"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/ErrorAppearance">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            style="@style/FormStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_https_grey600_18dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_https_grey600_18dp"
            android:hint="رمز عبور"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:transformPivotX="10dp"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true" />

  </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

add ErrorAppearance and FormStyle in the styles.xml

```
<style name="ErrorAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/textError</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font_small</item>
</style>


<style name="FormStyle">
       <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
       <item name="android:drawablePadding">@dimen/spacing_small</item>
       <item name="android:textColor">@color/textHint</item>
</style>
```

after the validation in the activity , you can :

```
pass_l.setError(getString(R.string.wrong_pass));
```